# Etherium based tokens

Tags: ethereum

When we say certain crypto currency is based over etherium, for instance TRON, does it mean they have used etherium code from github and modified as per their use case? Or is it something completely different?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better asked on the ethereum stack exchange.

Answer (score 6):

It is completely different. 
Ethereum offers a standardized way to create new tokens on its blockchain called the ERC-20 protocol. ERC-20 is not a piece of code, software, or technology. Rather, it is guidelines that facilitate the integration of various currencies.
Tron is an ethereum based token that means it is powered by Ethereum blockchain. It will use resources of the ETH blockchain Tron is not a blockchain started from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Actually ethereum based token uses Ethereum blockchain for transaction purposes and the code will be developed by their own according to their need  by using Solidity as the language most of the times.
But now Tron has come up with the mainnet that means they run their own blockchain and you can get the Tron explorer here https://tronscan.org/#/

If you observe carefully the public address of Tron it starts with "T" where as in Ethereum it starts "0x"

Answer (score 0):

> Does it mean they have used etherium code from github and modified as per their use case? Or is it something completely different?

It is something completely different.

It means that transactions involving the token happen on the Ethereum blockchain. You can see TRON transactions happening on the Ethereum blockchain here: https://etherscan.io/token/Tronix

Comment: So doesn’t it mean that TRON should be complying with etherium ecosystem, meaning TRON transaction should also be validated by etherium miners? But TRON has generated all its tokens at once and doesn’t allow mining on its currency.

Comment: Indeed, TRON cannot be mined, but TRON transactions happen on the ethereum blockchain and hence are validated by ETH miners. You can see the TX on the ETH blockchain that created TRON here: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9299ff8878c8a22306be0b79a740b6dcc76a4dc5307717a292879923930ba9bc . Notice how it paid a fee of 0.019416159 ETH for gas.

Comment: So basically Tron company pays etherium miners for validation of trx transactions?

Comment: @Safdar Mirza Anyone sending TRON tokens to anyone else pays ethereum miners for the TX. If you send TRON to someone named Bob, you pay the TX fee in ETH.

Comment: @SafdarMirza Just like if you send ETH to someone you need to pay an ETH fee, since the transaction happens on the ETH blockchain. If you send an ETH token like TRON to someone you need to pay an ETH fee since the transaction also happens on the ETH blockchain.